# Write dataframe to mysql table and set properties like primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, apache-spark

I want to write a dataframe to a mysql database and assign properties like primary key, auto_increment, etc to the created table.

I am using the com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. 
Import is:

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.11"
```

I checked connection properties and couldn't find anything there.

If the table alredy exists and I created it beforehand with a primary key it is possible to write into the table and keep the schema

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").option("truncate", "true").jdbc(connectionString, tableName, properties)
```

Is there a way to write a dataframe to a table that does not exist yet and set the primary key (maybe even with auto_increment property)

I did not find any way yet to accomplish this.

What I get is:
[image]

What I want is
[image]